# Sexually energetic person

Tags: single-word-requests

*Hi*
*What's the word for a person who is sexually strong?*
*sorry I have no context for that.*

Editing: Actually I wanted to describe my friend (boy) who was narrating his story to me and he said he had strong sex drive (I can't tell what he said) so I wanted to describe him.

Comment: Almost right and Appreciable BTW.

Comment: Are you just talking about a horny boyfriend?

Answer (score 2):

This word is gender neutral

> **libidinous**
>   ADJECTIVE
>
> Showing excessive sexual drive; lustful.
>   *When it first came out, swing was libidinous, hedonistic devil music.*

From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/libidinous).

Comment: I needed a word for a boy and virile is perfect for what I wanted to say. my friend is not horny or lustful. I edited my question. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a slang-word, horny seems to fit the bill as in **"a horny kind of person"**  Unlike "virile", which is a male trait, horny can be used for both men and women.

> - From [**Collins**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/horny) -sexually eager or lustful.  If you describe someone as horny, you mean that they are sexually aroused or that **they easily become sexually aroused**.

Then again, libido is a noun for sexual desire, which can be strong or absent. (loss of libido).  It isn't an adjective and, therefore, does not describe a person.

Comment: I needed a word for a boy and virile is perfect for what I wanted to say. my friend is not horny or lustful. I edited my question. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: In Britain "horny" would mean he had antlers. The equivalent might be "randy" - but then you think of that as someone's name. Two nations separated by a common language?

Comment: @SyedWasifAli  Your original question said "person", not "boy".  That's why I thought of a gender neutral adjective.  In addition, a boy who has a strong sexual drive is not necessarily "virile".  Srong sexual desire may present in different forms, and "virile" doesn't always fit.

Answer (score -1):

Erotically charged can also be used as a milder way to describe a person who is sexually strong.